# Do we need to use flatten and reshape in Theano if we use a matrix of indexes?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, lstm, flatten

I try to understand [Theano implementation of LSTM](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html) (at the moment the link does not work for whatever reason but I hope it will be back soon).

In the code I see the following part:

```
emb = tparams['Wemb'][x.flatten()].reshape([n_timesteps,
                                            n_samples,
                                            options['dim_proj']])
```

To make it "context independent" I rewrite it in the following way:

```
e = W[x.flatten()]].reshape([n1, n2, n3])
```

where dimension of `x` is `(n1, n2)` and dimension of `W` is `(N, n3)`.

So, my assumption is that the code can be rewritten to be shorter. In particular we can just write:

```
e = W[x]
```

Or, if we use the original notation it should be:

```
emb = tparams['Wemb'][x]
```

Am I right?

To provide a bit more context, `x` is a 2D array containing integers representing words (for example 27 means "word number 27"). The `W` in my notation (or `tparams['Wemb']`) in the original notation is a 2D matrix in which each row corresponds to a word. So, it is a word embedding matrix (Word2Vec) mapping each word to a real valued vector.

Comment: Edit your Question with **Real** example Data. Show `W.size` and `W.shape`, `x.size` and `x.shape`

Comment: Maybe the original is more descriptive "we retrieve rows from `W` with the values of `x` and end up with an array with shape `n1,n2,n3`". Good for a tutorial, where the code is from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

`W[x.flatten()]]` gives you the rows of `W` (i.e. words) defined by the values of `x`. So the result is of `shape = (n1*n2,n3)`. Let's call this "list of words" (not a python list, but just a common speech list).
Then reshaping gives you the desired size, where the list of words is subdevided in `n1` pages of `n2` words.

You achieve the same with `W[x]`, since every of the `n2` rows of `x` gives you one of the `n1` pages of the result.

Here's an example program that shows that both expressions are equivalent:

```
import numpy as np

N = 4
n3 = 5
W = np.arange(n3*N).reshape((N,n3))

print("W = \n", W)

n1 = 2
n2 = 3
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=N,size=(n1,n2))

print("\nx = \n", x)

print("\ne = \n", W[x.flatten()].reshape([n1, n2, n3]))

print("\nalternativeE = \n", W[x])
```